# PHP Syntax (Basic)

Tags: php, arrays, syntax

Yes, I am aware this is a basic question, but I am learning PHP.

```
   $sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE data = " . trim($array[$elementnum]);
   echo $sqlquery; //Returns correctly
   $queryresult = mysql_query($sqlquery);  
   var_dump($queryresult);               // returns false
   mysql_fetch_row($queryresult);      //Doesn't Work
```

How Do I do this properly? I want to select data from a table where a certain column is equal to the value of my array at a particular element. The array and element num are both variables

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: `echo $sqlquery;` is that what you expected?

Comment: No, it is not what I expect it to be.

Comment: I'm positive the data in the table should match

Comment: seems about right except you forgot to close trim )

Comment: can you show more code and the result as well ? it's hard to help without any clue on `$elementnum`

Comment: elementnum is a counter that holds 0 - a num to be determined

Comment: What the current output of `$sqlquery`? what's your expected output?

Comment: `$queryresult = mysql_query($sqlquery) or die(mysql_error());` add this to end of your line see if it gives you a message.

Comment: mysql_error says that I have incorrect syntax

Comment: `$sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE data = '" . trim($array[$elementnum]) . "'";` then try wrapping the value in quotes

Comment: AND when I hardcode the sql query without the array[elementnum] it works

Comment: are you sure *data* is the right column? is your table really named *table*? If so, wrap it in backtics `\`table\``

Comment: yes everything works except when I used a variable instead of a string with the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var_dump($queryresult);               // returns false
mysql_fetch_row($queryresult);      //Doesn't Work
```

Was the `var_dump` returning false a bit of a give away?

It means that your query did not work!

Comment: It works if I hardcode myquery without using my array

Comment: @Vlad - What is the output of $sqlquery? BTW - Use mysqli or PDO. It is better to use something that is not deprecated.

Comment: $sqlquery is empty, mysql returns an error.

Comment: My data will have a . in it? It says the error is occuring near that

Comment: $sqlquery is a string. At least it contains 'SELECT....'